# Trying to compare today's date to a date a month ago

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

I have an object that is loading configurations from a database. I store the last time that a job was run with a datetime field (called `GroupsLastRun`) and I store how often the job should run with a string field called `Captureusersandgroups`. `Captureusersandgroups` stores three different types 'DAILY', 'WEEKLY' and 'MONTHLY'.

Basically, I have a loop should only continue if the job is due to run. So far I've got to the following point:

```
if (configEntity.GroupsLastrun > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) && configEntity.Captureusersandgroups == "DAILY") continue;
if (configEntity.GroupsLastrun > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) && configEntity.Captureusersandgroups == "WEEKLY") continue;
if (configEntity.GroupsLastrun > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30) && configEntity.Captureusersandgroups == "MONTHLY") continue;
```

I'm sure (certain) there's a much better approach to this but primarily being a SQL Server developer I lack the critical thinking / tools for approaching this. What is a better approach or what should I learn so I can think about this better?

Comment: Is it working? It looks fine.

Comment: Please update your title http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: @JacobSeleznev It works - but this seems like a bad approach, doesn't it?

Comment: @SonerGönül Changed. Feel free to edit if you have better suggestions, hard to identify how to better label this one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few points:

- Unless you want to be at the mercy of time zones and daylight saving transitions etc, I'd use `DateTime.UtcNow` rather than `DateTime.Now` (and make sure you *store* the UTC value as well)
- As p.s.w.g. mentioned, it's worth only asking for the current date/time once - but rather than performance, I'd say that the important reason is for *consistency*. In this case it looks like you're only going to actually use one of the values, but in other cases I've seen people write conditions where two evaluations are used at the same time, leading to issues if the code is run over midnight
- You've got repeated code due to checking the condition *and* determining the deadline at the same time. I'd separate the two.

So, I'd have code like this:

```
// Consider whether you actually want DateTime.UtcNow.Date
DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;

DateTime deadline;
switch (configEntity.Captureusersandgroups)
{
    case "DAILY": deadline = now.AddDays(-1);
    case "WEEKYLY": deadline = now.AddDays(-7);
    case "MONTHLY": deadline = now.AddMonths(-1);
    // I'm assuming there's *always* a schedule
    default: throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid schedule");
}
if (configEntity.GroupsLastrun > deadline)
{
    continue;
}
```

Note that subtracting a month from "now" isn't the same as adding a month from "then". For example, if the last run was on January 30th, the next run won't be until March 1st using the above code - whereas if you added a month to January 30th, it would next be run on February 28th (unless you use the *dates* of both values). Consider carefully exactly the behaviour you want.

(As a quick plug, I'd also obviously recommend considering my [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) library for date/time work. It makes it clearer whether any particular value is a local time, or in some time zone etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Two points:

1. `DateTime.Now` can (potential) return a different date every time it's called. It's also not very fast. You'll get better consistency and a very slight performance boost by only calling it once.
2. You should probably use the standard methods for adding weeks and months, for consistency (e.g. there's not always 30 days in a month) and globalization (e.g. not all cultures have a 7-day week). Note that there's no easy way to add weeks with a `DateTime` alone; you'll have to use a [`Calendar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7y5k6h07.aspx) instead.

Try this:

```
var now = DateTime.UtcNow; // See Jon Skeet's answer
var cal = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar;
if (configEntity.GroupsLastrun > now.AddDays(-1) && configEntity.Captureusersandgroups == "DAILY") continue;
if (configEntity.GroupsLastrun > cal.AddWeeks(now, -1) && configEntity.Captureusersandgroups == "WEEKLY") continue;
if (configEntity.GroupsLastrun > now.AddMonths(-1) && configEntity.Captureusersandgroups == "MONTHLY") continue;
```

Or just use `cal` for everything:

```
var now = DateTime.UtcNow; // See Jon Skeet's answer
var cal = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar;
if (configEntity.GroupsLastrun > cal.AddDays(now, -1) && configEntity.Captureusersandgroups == "DAILY") continue;
if (configEntity.GroupsLastrun > cal.AddWeeks(now, -1) && configEntity.Captureusersandgroups == "WEEKLY") continue;
if (configEntity.GroupsLastrun > cal.AddMonths(now, -1) && configEntity.Captureusersandgroups == "MONTHLY") continue;
```

Comment: The *performance* boost from only calling `DateTime.Now` once isn't the important part IMO - it's the *consistency* boost. As for adding weeks - would you ever expect adding a week to be different to adding 7 days?

Comment: @JonSkeet I would never assume one week = 7 days in my code, if I want it to be culture independant. See [wikipedia: Week](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week)

Comment: That entry starts: "A week is a time unit equal to seven days". I realise there are other calendars where that's not true, but given that you're explicitly using the calendar from the invariant culture, it always *will* be 7 days anyway. Unless the OP *actually* needs to take account of non-Gregorian calendars (in which case there's a much bigger can of worms), it simplifies life significantly to assume that a week is 7 days.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes that's true, I just read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.addweeks.aspx) "In all .NET Framework classes derived from the `Calendar` class, a week is defined as seven days." I guess writing `.AddDays(-7)` feels too like a magic number to me, still, but there would likely be no harm in it.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative approach, you could possibly store the run period in an `enum` like :

```
enum RunPeriod
{
    Daily = 1,
    Weekly = 7,
    Monthly = 30
}
```

And then you can store the `int` values, instead of `string`, on the database. This allows you to do the filtering on the DB side, e.g.:

```
var configsToRun = 
    from c in _myContext.Configs
    where EntityFunctions.AddDays(c.LastRun,(int)c.RunPeriod) > DateTime.Now);
```